# Card Flip not working in IE10+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, animation, flip

I am trying to execute a card flip animation that holds throughout IE10+, but I'm hitting a rut given that the IE has no support for `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. I've seen multiple "fixes" for this, but none will work with my code.  I am hoping somebody from this awesome community can step in and help me figure out this hot mess!!  Any and all help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you so much in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/rebeccatcook/E8mLp/

Comment: A useful site: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d but in short IE10 only partially supports 3d transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer supports transform-style since version 11 so you should be fine there. IE10 supports 3D transforms, but as you point out, does not support the transform-style property which specifies how nested elements are rendered in 3D space. This is why you are not seeing your "Back text".

I'm not sure what "fixes" your referring to but the common practice is to simply leverage "fall-back animations" that are supported by the specific browser version. For IE10 I would use modernizr to sniff browser features and append custom CSS classes to implement a a simple fade in/out effect.

If you absolutely have to have this effect without JavaScript, you could use IE Matrix filters but it can be a time suck getting it to act right. Here's a reference point: http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

Good luck!